# Pandas left join DataFrames by two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Could you please help me with joining two DataFrames.

I have two DataFrames.

df1:

```
index   val1    val2
--------------------
1       str1    abc1
2       str2    abc2
3       str3    abc3
4       str4    abc9
5       str5    abc4
```

df2:

```
index   val2
------------
1       abc1
2       abc2
4       abc3 
5       abc4
9       abc5
```

I need to create a DataFrame based on the previous two with a left join by two columns. Columns index and val2 have the same names in both DataFrames. The result of df3 should look like this:

```
index   val1    val2    val3
----------------------------
1       str1    abc1    1
2       str2    abc2    1
3       str3    abc3    NaN
4       str4    abc9    NaN
5       str5    abc4    1
```

Indexes from df2 that are not present in df1 should be dropped, if an index in df1 has the same val2 as in df2 then 1 should be added to a new column val3, else: NaN.

Huge thanks in advance!

Comment: is `index` a column named index or the actual index of the `DataFrame`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one way. As below, I recommend you use Boolean rather than `float` for `val3`, as this what the series represents.

```
# merge and set index
res = df1.merge(df2, how='left').set_index('index')

# map val2 from df2
res['val3'] = df2.set_index('index')['val2']

# check for equality of val3 and val2
res['val3'] = res['val3'] == res['val2']

print(res)

       val1  val2   val3
index                   
1      str1  abc1   True
2      str2  abc2   True
3      str3  abc3  False
4      str4  abc9  False
5      str5  abc4   True
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `join` (*default is left*) with `rsuffix` so that column name for df2 is renamed with suffix. Then, using `np.where` to check if column value matches and assigning value for `val3` column.

```
import numpy as np

df = df1.join(df2, rsuffix='_df2')
df['val3'] = np.where(df.val2 == df.val2_df2, 1, np.NaN)
del df['val2_df2']
print(df)
```

Result:

```
       val1  val2  val3
index                  
1      str1  abc1   1.0
2      str2  abc2   1.0
3      str3  abc3   NaN
4      str4  abc9   NaN
5      str5  abc4   1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to merge on a combination of indices and columns you can either add them all to the index, or `reset_index` before the merge. We'll also assign the `val3` column to df2 so it gets merged over.

```
(df1.reset_index().merge(
     df2.reset_index().assign(val3 = 1), on=['index', 'val2'], how='left')
    .set_index('index'))
```

Outputs:

```
       val1  val2  val3
index                  
1      str1  abc1   1.0
2      str2  abc2   1.0
3      str3  abc3   NaN
4      str4  abc9   NaN
5      str5  abc4   1.0
```

---

If `'index'` is just a column and not the index, it's as simple as specifying two keys to merge on.

```
df1.merge(df2.assign(val3 = 1), on=['index', 'val2'], how='left')
```

Outputs:

```
   index  val1  val2  val3
0      1  str1  abc1   1.0
1      2  str2  abc2   1.0
2      3  str3  abc3   NaN
3      4  str4  abc9   NaN
4      5  str5  abc4   1.0
```